# Forgot to add transaction fee, any way to add it now?

Tags: transaction-fees

Today I sent 1.5 BTC to an exchange but forgot to add a transaction fee, the Qt wallet didn't even prompt me with one and I just clicked on Yes. Now [it's been over 2 hours](https://blockchain.info/tx/7242efd299b3fe2dae04567b4778bb89cacd873a71b1ac16498e7014509bb7a2) and it's not confirmed (as you would have guessed).

I kinda needed it to reach the exchange quickly (I know, my fault), but now is there any way to speed this up or do I have to wait it out for days to arrive at the destination?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wait it out. Both of your inputs are around 1BTC so your transaction will likely be bumped up to "high priority" status in the next 12-24 hours.

Comment: ... and it is confirmed. You never know, some miners don't mind no-fee transactions.